# How do I allow the user to save the file to their computer

Tags: python, pyaudio

I am writing a voice recording program. I want the code to record audio and once the audio is done recording, it will automatically save it to my computer so that it can be listened to later. My code is below:

```
import pyaudio
import wave


FRAMES_PER_BUFFER = 3200
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 16000

pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = pa.open(
    format=FORMAT,
    channels=CHANNELS,
    rate=RATE,
    input=True,
    frames_per_buffer=FRAMES_PER_BUFFER
)

print('start recording')

seconds = 3
frames = []
second_tracking = 0
second_count = 0
for i in range(0, int(RATE/FRAMES_PER_BUFFER*seconds)):
    data = stream.read(FRAMES_PER_BUFFER)
    frames.append(data)
 


stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
pa.terminate()

obj = wave.open('Recordings.wav', 'wb')
obj.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
obj.setsampwidth(pa.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
obj.setframerate(RATE)
obj.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
obj.close()
```

I know that it is recording but I can't figure out how to save the audio that is being recorded to my computer once the time runs out/ the recording stops.

Comment: What exactly happens, what should happen? If there is an error message, show it completely as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: This code works fine for me and saves`Recordings.wav` in the current directory. What is the error?